# AngularJS Parse JSON Array Objects Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I've tried searching through StackOverflow regarding this issue but could not find a solution that worked for me. I'm using AngularJS. I have simple controller that calls a http service and reads the response data. In this specific case, I have a JSON output with an objects array I am unable to read.

Here's the JSON output:

```
{
  "results": [{
    "id": "1",
    "download_url": "",
    "uploader": {
      "id": "114899"
    },
    "uploaded": "1442599380",
    "streaming_url_timeout": 1446092554
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "download_url": "",
    "uploader": {
      "id": "114899"
    },
    "uploaded": "1442599380",
    "streaming_url_timeout": 1446092554
  }]
}
```

I'm trying to get access to items in 'results'. This is my Service that retrieves the JSON data:

```
this.getUData = function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http.jsonp(API_URL + 'udata')
    .success(function(data) {
      deferred.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function(data) {
      deferred.reject(data);
    });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

And then this is how i call this service from my controller:

```
myservices.getUData().then(function(data) {
   $scope.uitems = data.results;
});
```

Template:

```
<div class="item" href="#" ng-repeat="item in uitems">
  <h2>{{item.id}}</h2>
</div>
```

But when I try to access the items in 'results', I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

The line in question for this error is    `"results":[`

Comment: Try using ng-repeat="item in uitems.results". Becase the element results is an array of your json response on which you can use ng-repeat

Comment: @J-D, no change in result I'm afraid.

Comment: @ngLover, not solved.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in this case the callback function was not working correctly on the PHP server so I managed to get away by using the 'GET' method in the $http service like so:

```
this.getUData = function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

$http({method: 'GET', url: API_URL + 'udata'})
    .success(function(data) {
      deferred.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function(data) {
      deferred.reject(data);
    });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```